# Does a symmetric positive definite matrix also have $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{L}^T\mathbf{L}$ (where $\mathbf{L}$ is a lower triangular matrix)?

Tags: matrix, matrix-factorization, symmetry

As we know, for a symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrix $\mathbf{A}$, there is a theorem about the **Cholesky factorization** $\mathbf{A}= \mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}^T$, where $\mathbf{L}$ is a lower triangular matrix.
I am  a little curious whether the factorization $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{L}^T\mathbf{L}$ exists for a SPD matrix $\mathbf{A}$, where $\mathbf{L}$ is still a lower triangular matrix. Textbooks just give the first theorem not the second form. Though a teacher said that the second form also exists, I still have some doubts about that. Any hints and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $P$ be the anti-diagonal permutation matrix,
$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
& & & 1 \\
& & 1 \\
& 1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$
so that $PAP$ is the version of $A$ with rows and columns reversed. The first $P$ swaps the rows, and the last $P$ swaps the columns. We have the Cholesky decomposition
$$PAP=LL^T$$
which implies
$$A = (PLP)(PLP)^T,$$
since $P^{-1}=P$. But now $PLP$ is upper triangular, so this is a factorization of $A$ into a product of an upper triangular matrix times a lower triangular matrix.

Comment: Thanks Prof Nick, I get it. I also want to ask that though there are many factorizations for SPD matrix, but why  **matlab**  just choose this form $A=LL^T$, where **L** is lower triangular. Is this form the most classic form？so matlab choose this one and many monographs also introduce this one? And the monographs do not introdce a little about other factorizations.

Comment: @Zhen-WeiSun I'm not sure why books present it this way. But since the Cholesky factorization of a SPD matrix is unique, there are really only two possible symmetric triangular factorizations: $LL^T$ and $L^TL$. These factorizations are more useful than the LU factorization because they can be used to draw samples from a Gaussian with covariance $A^{-1}$ by computing $L^{-1}z$, $z\sim N(0,I)$. They are cheaper than the QR and eigenvalue decompositions because they often have less fill-in when $A$ is sparse. (also, I'm not a professor, but I'm flattered that you thought I was)

Comment: What you call the "anti-diagonal permutation matrix" is more commonly known as the "exchange matrix".

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, I didn't know that

Answer (score 6):

Yes, for an SPD matrix $\mathbf A$ there are a variety of Cholesky-like decompositions, you can derive the $\mathbf A = \mathbf L^T \mathbf L$ variant by first writing down an educated/structured guess..

$\begin{bmatrix}
 \mathbf A_{11} & \mathbf a_{21}^T \\ 
 \mathbf a_{21} & \alpha_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \mathbf L_{11}^T & \mathbf l_{21}^T \\ 
 \mathbf 0 & \lambda_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \mathbf L_{11} & \mathbf 0 \\ 
 \mathbf l_{21} & \lambda_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$

.. where the **bold** items are matrices/row vectors and the greek items are scalars. Next, multiply out the right side and equate it block-by-block to the left side, to deduce the following relationships between $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf L$:

- Equate (1,1) blocks: $\mathbf A_{11} = \mathbf L_{11}^T \mathbf L_{11} + \mathbf l_{21}^T \mathbf l_{21}$
- Equate (2,1) blocks: $\mathbf a_{21} = \lambda_{22} \mathbf l_{21}$
- Equate (2,2) blocks: $\alpha_{22} = \lambda_{22} \lambda_{22}$

When properly sequenced (work from known quantities towards unknown ones), these relationships define the algorithm:

1. Compute $\lambda_{22} = \sqrt{\alpha_{22}}$, a scalar square root.
2. Scale $\mathbf l_{21} = \lambda_{22}^{-1} \mathbf a_{21}$, a row scaling.
3. Update $ \mathbf { \tilde A_{11} } = \mathbf A_{11} - \mathbf l_{21}^T \mathbf l_{21}$, a rank-1 outer product update.
4. Factor $\mathbf { \tilde A_{11} } = \mathbf L_{11}^T \mathbf L_{11}$, tail-recursion into the upper left submatrix.

LAPACK uses a similar algorithm whenever you apply Choleskly decomposition [potrf] to "upper" triangular storage (it forms $\mathbf A = \mathbf U \mathbf U^T$). All four of the decompositions ($\mathbf L \mathbf L^T$, $\mathbf L^T \mathbf L$, $\mathbf U \mathbf U^T$, $\mathbf U^T \mathbf U$) are possible and can be derived using similar ideas.

Comment: Thanks Prof Rchilton for your clear and detailed explanation, I get it. I also want to ask that though there are many factorizations for SPD matrix, but why  **matlab**  just choose this form $A=LL^T$, where **L** is lower triangular. Is this form the most classic form？so matlab choose this one and many monographs also introduce this one? And the monographs do not introdce a little about other factorizations.

Comment: As you can see from the answers, all these variants are basically equivalent : triangular factorizations, that furnish the inverse operator, and properly exploit the symmetry/positivity. I guess the $\mathbf L \mathbf L^T$ variant is considered the canonical choice .. probably because it's the one that is most similar in structure/implementation to the $\mathbf L \mathbf U$ decomposition. That being said, there's nothing special about $\mathbf L \mathbf U$ either! It too can be rearranged into other/similar triangular factorizations, just like Cholesky.

Comment: Get it. Many thanks for Prof Richilton's reply. I thouroughly understand it. Best wishes.;-)

Answer (score 4):

Since a SPD matrix is invertible, we can make the Cholesky decomposition $A^{-1} = PP^T$.

Since $A$ is non-singular, so is $P$, and the inverse of a triangular matrix is triangular, so writing $L = P^{-1}$ we have $A^{-1}$ = $L^{-1}L^{-T}$.

Inverting both sides gives $A = L^TL$.

Comment: Thanks for your concise and clear explanation.;-)